# Setting linear-gradient with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, linear-gradients

I am trying to change the background of my website to a linear gradient of different colours with javascript. The background is changing but to a solid colour, not a linear gradient.

I logged the background and it shows the new linear gradient so I "know" it is setting the style.

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Kosugi Maru', sans-serif;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(140, 202, 165), 
    rgb(198,159,197), rgb(248, 160, 133), rgb(52,219,216));
}
```

```
function generateGradient(one, two, three) {
    let lessOne = one;
    let moreOne = one;
    let lessTwo = two;
    let moreTwo = two;
    let lessThree = three;
    let moreThree = three;

    if (one >= 10) {
        lessOne = one - 10;
    }
    if (two >= 10) {
        lessTwo = two - 10;
    }
    if (three >= 10) {
        lessThree = three - 10;
    }

    if (one <= 245) {
        moreOne = one + 10;
    }
    if (two <= 245) {
        moreTwo = two + 10;
    }
    if (three <= 245) {
        moreThree = three + 10;
    }

    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(' + lessOne + ',' + lessTwo + ',' + lessThree + '), rgb(' + one + ',' + two + ',' + three + '), rgb(' + moreOne + ',' + moreTwo + ',' + moreThree + '))';
}
```

Comment: How did you call the function, and what got logged?

Comment: @Ry-         generateGradient(colourOne, colourTwo, colourThree);
 and console.log(document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundImage) and linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(56, 76, 162), rgb(66, 86, 172), rgb(76, 96, 182))

Comment: Hmm… can you reproduce it in a Stack Snippet, [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/), or other live link form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I little change your code, maybe that what you need:

```html
 &nbsp;
    <style>
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        font-family: 'Kosugi Maru', sans-serif;
        background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(140, 202, 165),
            rgb(198, 159, 197), rgb(248, 160, 133), rgb(52, 219, 216));
    }
    </style>
    <script>
    function generateGradient(one, two, three) {
        let lessOne = one;
        let moreOne = one + 120;
        let lessTwo = two;
        let moreTwo = two + 120;
        let lessThree = three;
        let moreThree = three + 120;

        if ((moreOne + 120) > 255) {
            moreOne = moreOne - 255;
        }
        if ((moreTwo + 120) > 255) {
            moreTwo = moreTwo - 255;
        }
        if ((moreThree + 120) > 255) {
            moreThree = moreThree - 255;
        }

        document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(' + lessOne + ',' + lessTwo + ',' + lessThree + '), rgb(' + one + ',' + two + ',' + three + '), rgb(' + moreOne + ',' + moreTwo + ',' + moreThree + '))';
    }

    generateGradient(10, 100, 245)
    </script>
```

Comment: I don't think we need the generate gradient anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, my bad. The forcing of color to black shows the gradient is working though, looks like the color shift may not be enough. Because you are adjusting by 10 on each R,G and B, it really is not the significant.

```js
function generateGradient(one, two, three) {
    let lessOne = one;
    let moreOne = one;
    let lessTwo = two;
    let moreTwo = two;
    let lessThree = three;
    let moreThree = three;

    if (one >= 10) {
        lessOne = one - 10;
    }
    if (two >= 10) {
        lessTwo = two - 10;
    }
    if (three >= 10) {
        lessThree = three - 10;
    }

    if (one <= 245) {
        moreOne = one + 10;
        moreOne = 0;
    }
    if (two <= 245) {
        moreTwo = two + 10;
        moreTwo = 0;
    }
    if (three <= 245) {
        moreThree = three + 10;
        moreThree = 0;
    }
    
    let style = `linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(${lessOne}, ${lessTwo} , ${lessThree} ) , rgb(${one}, ${two}, ${three}) , rgb(${moreOne}, ${moreTwo}, ${moreThree}))`;
    console.log(style);

    document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].style.backgroundImage = style;
}

generateGradient(5, 210, 50);
```

```css
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Kosugi Maru', sans-serif;
    background-image: linear-gradient(45deg, rgb(140, 202, 165), 
    rgb(198,159,197), rgb(248, 160, 133), rgb(52,219,216));
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>TEST</div>
</body>
```